# Control time of execute when i launch other app

Tags: android, android-activity, time, task

I have a doubt, I would like to know how I can do the following:

I have an activity that opens a file, depending on the type of the file (e.g. jpeg, mp4, pdf), with a default application of an android system. For example, if the file is pdf, it is opened by acrobat reader. As a consequence of that, my application in the background. It would be something like this
    private Date date;
    private Date restart;

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    //Layout code
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idButton);
    button.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:com.google.zxing.client.android");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                try
                {
                    date=new Date();
                    myActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                }
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    });
```

}

So, what I’m doing to count the time it takes the file from the external application is launched until it returns to my application is saved like this:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    savedInstanceState.putString("myDate", date.toString());

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    restart = (Date) savedInstanceState.getString("myDate");
    Date timenow = new Date();
    int timeWorking = timenow.getDate() - restart.getDate(); 
}
```

So, when the file returns to my application, it should have been saved and when restoring data, have the possibility to observe the moment when the previous application was released.

But the problem is that it is not working.

Any help or other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Measuring from onStop() to onStart() may better fit your goal, but realize the user could go somewhere else in the meantime, too.

Comment: Yes i only want to know the time that my app is not on front when my app start other application